# Is is possible to enable intellisense for XAML binding to view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I always used such obvious names for my fields in the view model so that I actually don't need the intellisense. However, I just discovered that I'd need it when working with code from programmers insisting on using non-english names (because "*coding is much easier when one uses the native tongue*").

So the question is - is it possible to make XAML intellisense to provide me with the list of fields in the view model (easily, that is)?

C#

```
public ElViewoConstructo()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = new ElViewoModello();
}
```

XAML

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Path=Donkey}"
             Minimum="0"
             Value="{Binding Path=Monkey}"
             Visibility="{Binding Path=Wonkey.Bonky}" />
```

If it's possible, I'm guessing that I'd need to register the data context in some way. Surprisingly though, I couldn't find anything useful by Google. It's possible that I'm using a wrong set of search words but I got only intellisense questions on SQL Management Studio...

Comment: `programmers insisting on using non-english names` - should be banned from programming forever. And this comes from a non-english native speaker.

Comment: @HighCore I've heard but two arguments for such. One is that native language makes it easier. The other is that naming of entities is country specific. Both are wrong and one of them is just plain stupid.

Comment: my client has entire codebase in Turkish, while migrating, I felt learning Turkish is easier

Comment: @CodeNameJack I'm impressed. And a bit worried. I'd like to translate every non-english variable and class into a random combinations of characters. Then, I'd push it down the author's  throat claiming it's a cool language X they aren't familiar with. Than, watch them suffer... At any rate, the keywords aren't translatable and we land into a weird combination of English and native anyway. There's a special corner in hell for programmers doing that, hahaha.   :)

Answer (score 21):

Either set the DataContext in XAML:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
      <local:ElViewoModello/>
  <Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

or use [`d:DataContext`](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/) to define the design-time DataContext type:

```
<Window d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ElViewoModello}"/>
```

You may need to add

```
xmlns:mc="schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

to your xaml.

Comment: @LeeO. Oh, so the second suggestion in the reply is rather a hack-around, right? In such case, I prefer the first one. Are there any cons/pros to any of them?

Comment: @KonradViltersten no it's not a hack-around, it's the proper way to define design time data.

Comment: Second sugestion worked like a charm. Thanks FedericoBerasategui